# msdeploy via powershell and psake fails

Tags: powershell, msdeploy, psake

So I'm trying to use powershell and psake for my build and deployment. I've tried without any success to call the following psake task.

```
Exec { msdeploy.exe "-verb:sync"
"-source:package="D:\path-to-package\zip-file-name.zip"
"-dest:auto,computername=http://my-server-name-here:8090/MsDeployAgentService2/" -setparam:Name="IIS Web Application Name,Value=iis-web-app-name-here" "-allowUntrusted" }
```

So in an effort to get things moving I removed the offending `setparam:Name="IIS Web Application Name,Value=iis-web-app-name-here"`. It worked but took the IIS Web Application Name parameter from the ..SetParameters.xml as expected.

```
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/project.name_deploy" />
```

There's clearly something wrong with the syntax of `setparam:Name="IIS Web Application Name,Value=iis-web-app-name-here"` but I've tried a dozen (or more) variations including

```
-setparam:"IIS Web Application Name=iis-web-app-name-here" > omitting the name,value

-setparam:"IIS` Web` Application` Name=iis-web-app-name-here" > using back ticks
```

I really can't work out what I'm doing wrong and may have to resort back to using an msbuild file to get things moving.

The error I receive is : > all arguments must begin with -

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to quote the parameters as follows:

```
setparam:Name="IIS Web Application Name",Value="iis-web-app-name-here"
```

Note the additional quotes before the comma and after the equals sign following Value.

Comment: Thanks. I no longer have the PSake script as I reverted back to MSDeploy. Next time I pick PSake I'll give it a whirl.